# Can't call objects from class in loop Python Django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

I an newbee to Django and I realise that it is a very silly question but, when I put objects in a HTML code to call `index` from data base I recieve just text of what I am calling: `List of news(item.title)(item.title)(item.title)(item.title)`

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import News

def index(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    res = '<hi>List of news</h1>'
    for item in news:
        res += f'<div><p>(item.title)</p></div>'
    return HttpResponse(res)
```

Comment: Please go through a _tutorial_ for Django once. Look at the official one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/ specifically you should pay more attention to Part 3 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/ which talks about the templating system.

Comment: Okay, i will reread it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import News

def index(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    res = '<hi>List of news</h1>'
    for item in news:
       res += f'<div><p>{item.title}</p></div>'
    return HttpResponse(res)
```